# Python requests module: Equivalent of cURL --data command

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, urlencode

I'm trying to write a script that imitates a cURL command I make to change data on the target web page:

```
curl -u username:password "https://website.com/update/"  --data "simChangesList=%5B%7B%22simId%22%3A760590802%2C%22changeType%22%3A2%2C%22targetValue%22%3A%220003077%22%2C%22effectiveDate%22%3Anull%7D%5D" --compressed
```

As you can see above, I am POSTing a url-encoded string to the target web page.

The following code does not work:

```
import requests
import urllib

enc = urllib.quote('[{"simId":760590802,"changeType":2,"targetValue":000307,"effectiveDate":null}]')
simChangesList = 'simChangesList=' + enc
print simChangesList
auth = s.post(url, data=simChangesList)
print auth.text
```

Even though I'm fairly certain the above code imitates my cURL command previously, but it obviously isn't.

I am getting a `Required List parameter 'simChangesList' is not present` error.

What is the equivalent of the cURL command to POST a url-encoded string with the requests module in Python?

EDIT:

I've tried to make multiple dictionaries with simChangesList as the key, but I cannot seem to do it.

Here are my attempts:

```
simChangesList: [{"simId":760590802,"changeType":2,"targetValue":000307,"effectiveDate":null}]

data = {'simChangesList': ['simId': 760590802, 'changeType': 2, 'targetValue': '0003077', 'effectiveDate': null]}
data['simChangesList'] = ['simId': 760590802, 'changeType': 2, 'targetValue': '0003077', 'effectiveDate': null]
simChangesList:[{"simId":760590802,"changeType":2,"targetValue":"000307","effectiveDate":null}]

payload = {
'simChangesList':
[{'simId': '760590802',
'changeType': '2',
'targetValue': '0003077',
'effectiveDate': 'null'}]
}
```

Comment: You'll need a dictionary with `simChangesList` as the key

Comment: @cricket_007 How do I add multiple key/values to one master key? I've been trying for ages but I cannot seem to get it right.

Comment: What do you mean? `{'simChangesList' : []}` is how requests would like to send the data, at least for json api

Comment: @cricket_007 Looking at my editing question, I've tried to make a dict many times. I'm not sure how I should fully format my dict.

Comment: How long did you say you were trying? https://curl.trillworks.com

Comment: @cricket_007 For a few days now, wow, I can't thank you enough for that link! Many thanks!!

Comment: Lol. Hopefully that works

Comment: @cricket_007 It works! I feel so ashamed having tried for a while to find such a simple tool. Oh well, all in all a learning experience; can't complain about that. Again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to post your own answer to the question

Comment: @juiceb0xk Check http://pycurl.io/ or libcurl package.